# Bootstrap: Stacked nav bar shows a border on content when minimized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the stacked nav-bar to create a vertical menu. The problem with the nav-bar is that when I minimize my window, there is some border around the tab contents. I am rendering a table in the content section.

Full screen size
[image: Screen shot when screen is maximized]

---

Minimized Screen
[image]

---

I cannot figure out why is the faint border showing around the table when minimized. How do I remove it?

---

```
  <div class="row-fluid"> 
    <div class="tabbable">
    <!-- Tab contents --> 
    {{ show_tabs_vertical(tab.content.moreTabs) }}
    <div class="tab-content col-md-9 col-xs-10"> 
      {% for tab in tab.content.moreTabs %}
      <div id="{{tab.div_id}}" class="tab-pane">
      {{ show_table(tab) }}
      </div> <!-- Tab Div ID -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

---

The markup is working fine and I haven't defined any borders anywhere.

Comment: Code example and an arrow pointing to the problem specifically would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your table is wrapped in a `table-responsive` class.  This class allows the table to become scrollable (horizontally) when the screen goes below 768px.  It also adds a border. See `_tables.css` in the bootstrap source.

Check to see what type of default wrapper classes `show_table` might be adding.

Comment: It was table-responsive indeed. Even without the responsive feature, somehow I am getting the scroll bar on minimizing the screen. Thanks.

Comment: Cool.  I've also noticed some weird movement (left to right) when using jQuery DataTables even at full screen.  If I figure it out, I'll let you know.

Comment: Changing <table-responsive> to <table> will not work as it will take away responsiveness and horizontal scroll on table will be lost. Just add  <style="border: 0px"> and the border will be lost.